# IIS Site Inheritance

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, webserver, iis-7.5

I'm looking for advice on how to handle multiple web.configs in a single IIS site.  I have little experience in IIS but need to figure this out.

Background:
1) We have an intranet application running on a single site in IIS 7.5
2) We have custom application code on various servers that we iframe into our intranet and want to piggy-back on our intranet's URL. (intranet.com/custom/blah.aspx)
3) To accomplish this we created virtual directories within our IIS intranet site. Unfortunately, this appears to cause some inheritance/conflict between our intranet's web.config and the web.configs for our various custom applications.

My initial thought is that perhaps we need to remove our custom applications from our IIS intranet site and create  new IIS site, but I’m not sure if/how this would be possible as we still want to piggy back on the same URL.
Any ideas?

Let me know if additional detail/clarification is needed.

Comment: Set them up as separate sites and re-organize the URL by reverse proxy, if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks Lex - how would I go about re-organizing the URL by reverse proxy?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can still go ahead with your existing setup i.e. having custom applications as virtual directories in your intranet application.Its just you need to resolve conflicts in web.config. There are two ways to resolve those conflicts.

1. Tell your intranet application's web.config not to push its configurations  on child directories. Way to achieve this is use location tag. e.g.
   If you want parent app not to push its connection strings to children directories then use following construct.

   `<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
      <connectionStrings>
      </connectionStrings>
   </location>`

   If you wrap all those conflicting settings in location element then it will not get pushed to children directories. You have to be cautious here as it will stop inheritance to intranet application's own child directories and not just virtual directories.
2. Tell your custom application's web.config not to inherit configurations from parent directories. Way to achieve this is use `<clear/>` element.
   In your custom application's web.config for all those conflicting settings you first clear settings coming from parent and then add specific settings you want to add. e.g.

   `<connectionStrings>
      <clear />
      <add your specific connection string>
   <connectionStrings>`

Comment: Thanks Pankaj - I'll give the second option a try as the intranet's web.config gets over-written by them every time we do an upgrade and I'm afraid of the downstream implications within the intranet that you referred to. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Pankaj, I gave it a try but it didn't work. it still inherited